# trying to reach a SpringBoot controller with Postman without success

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I use a Springboot application. Here is the controller

```java
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service.ReferenceService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api"})
public class ReferenceController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReferenceController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ReferenceService referenceService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/referenceData/findPostalCode", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List < String > findPostalCode(@RequestParam("postalCodeHint") String postalCodeHint) {
        return referenceService.findPostalCode(postalCodeHint);
    }
}
```

After starting the SpringBoot application, I try to reach the following url with Postman without success

```
http://127.0.0.0:8080/api/referenceData/findPostalCode?postalCodeHint=595
```

### UPDATE

I fixed the timeout to 300000 ms (5mn) on Postman

[image: enter code here]

But after less than this period I get a timeout for the request

[image]

Furthermore, when I hit 'http://127.0.0.0, I get also a timeout

[image]

I checked that there is the process of my application that is running

[image]

Comment: and your error message, error status code is what or should we just guess?

Comment: you can start by calling localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First when I made a $ping localhost, I realized that the ip is "127.0.0.1" and not "127.0.0.0". After that I had a 403 forbidden error, because I have a Spring security configured. So, I set up the following permission

```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http         
        .headers()
         .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
         .and()
           .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/**/*").permitAll();
```

And now, it works. Thank you for your help